# How to fix 'The requested resource does not exist' error message for 'lightning-record-form' in Community page

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, experience-cloud

I am getting the below error in Community when I am using 'lightning-record-form' in my code. My code is working fine inside Salesforce but in community it is always throwing me below error on Save. Can anyone please help me how to fix this issue:

[image]

*testRecordForm.html*

```
<template>
<div title="Cricket Match" class="slds-box mycolor">
    <lightning-record-form
    object-api-name="TestObject__c"
    fields={fields}
    columns="2"
    mode="edit">
</lightning-record-form>
```

*testRecordForm.js*

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import TESTNAME from '@salesforce/schema/TestObject__c.Test_Name__c';
export default class LightningRecordFormEditExampleLWC extends LightningElement {
@api matchId;
fields = [TESTNAME];
handleSubmit(event){
    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: 'Sucess!',
        message: 'Match Data Saved!',
        variant: 'success',
        mode: 'dismissable'
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Looks like it is related to this [Known Issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001GN1gQAG&title=community-guest-user-may-see-the-error-the-requested-resource-does-not-exist-while-creating-record-from-community-using-the-lightning-recordeditform). If it is, try with the workaround provided as of now.

Comment: @HemantJain Okay, what should we write in handleSubmit() in case of LWC. I don't have these two attributes in LWC-disabled, showSpinner. Do I create these two variables. Please guide?

Comment: The workaround mentions to navigate user to any page where they can access. Refer last line of the workaround code

Comment: It didn't work I tried the code it didn't navigate.